# VBA regex look ahead

Tags: regex, vba, regex-lookarounds

`enter code here`I'm trying to identify numbers that may be attached to a port after a "."
The format of the ports is ge-#/#/# (can be ge-0/0/n where 0 <= n <=23, or ge-0/1/m where 0 <= m <= 3)

Example:

```
ge-0/0/10.2014
```

The result should be "2014"

Currently, I'm using the following RegEx to identify the ports:

```
\bge-0/(0/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])|1/[0-3])\b
```

My problem is creating a check for the port, but only printing what's after it. My attempts to start simply and then toss in the port code are having poor results. If anyone could help create the RegEx I'm looking for and explain how it checks for the port without printing it, they would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Edit:
Only the pattern may be changed to solve this problem. This is because the pattern is being put into a txt file that will be read from by a vba macro. The vba code cannot be modified.

Comment: You tagged your question "vba" and "nsregularexpression". One is Microsoft, the other is Apple; is that correct? And why is `ge` followed by a dash in the regex, and a slash in all examples?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't see the ns. I'm using VBA The "ge/" was a typo, it should be "ge-". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand your regex with a capturing subpattern for the additional number `\.([0-9]+)`:

```
Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "\bge-0/(0/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])|1/[0-3])\.([0-9]+)\b"
```

Use `SubMatches` to retrieve the subpattern; refer to index 2, as there are two preceding pairs of parentheses in the regex.

```
Dim source, matches, result
Set source = "ge-0/0/10.2014"
If regEx.test(source) Then
    Set matches = regEx.Execute(source)
    Set result = matches(0).SubMatches(2)
End If
```

Comment: Unfortunately the solution must be limited to modifying the pattern/RegEx string, otherwise you would have solved it :) cheers.

Comment: Please explain and describe the exact limitations; just what _can_ you do with the regex? Do you have access to capturing subpatterns, or only to the string matching the entire pattern? Are you able to use RegExp's Execute and Replace methods? Are you allowed to do any string manipulations afterwards on the match?

Comment: I've updated my original post, there is an "Edit" section at the end which has more info on the limitations

Comment: Thanks for the update. Normally, this would be easy peasy with a lookbehind: `(?<=\bge-0/(0/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])|1/[0-3])\.)[0-9]+\b` But from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x(v=vs.84).aspx) I gather VBA's RegExp does not support lookbehind. Looks like you're totally out of luck here; I see no alternative but to modify the VBA code, or add some post-processing code to strip the match of its prefix. Or maybe do some pre-processing, reversing the part before and after the dot? Then you can use lookforward.